# Android Studio : App works on API 29 but crash on API 26

Tags: android, crash, logcat, android-bitmap

The application is working as fine without any unexpected behavior in API 29 emulator and on API 24 phone but crashes in API 26. **The app crashes when it starts. After the splashscreen.** I'm fairly new to android I don't understand why this happend.

My LogCag :

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2020-03-21 03:22:09.496 21362-21362/com.codebees.scaner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.codebees.scaner, PID: 21362
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(113550336bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
        at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1367)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20373)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19318)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20096)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19309)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20096)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20376)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19318)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20096)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19309)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20096)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19309)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20096)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19309)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20096)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19309)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20096)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4421)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4207)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20376)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:980)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:19318)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:686)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:800)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3496)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:3283)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2818)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1780)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7827)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

It says that "trying to draw too large(113550336bytes) bitmap." but I dont know which one because I only have xml drawable and 2 png

My Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.codebees.scaner"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks !

**EDIT :** I found which png is causing the problem but I dont know how to resolve it, I comment the ImageView to test and it doesnt crash anymore.
This is the ImageView in cause :

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cross"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

And the drawable cross is a 1776x1776 alpha png but it got a glow effect
I though I must vectorize this but I would lost my glowy effect

Comment: is your png under drawable-xxhdpi folder else add your png to [drawable folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31069202/8035260).

Comment: I only have a drawable folder so I guess everything is still in that folder

Comment: I just found where the problem comes but idk how to resolve it

Comment: Please have a look on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60251167/where-to-store-images-in-android/60310540#60310540)

Comment: I resized my png to 1440px x 1440px and now is 84kb but now It says this :
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 107869008 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 89MB until OOM`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by reducing my png to 1024x1024 and 70kb size

Seems to work now